# R: Modeling random intercepts from lme4 or brms objects

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, lme4, brms

Is there some way of directly (jointly) modeling the random intercepts estimated with `lme4`'s `lmer()` or `brms`? For example, in the below code I fit a hierarchical model, extract the random intercepts, then model them.

One downside to this two-step approach is that I am ignoring the error in the intercepts. This is easily fixed with a robust covariance matrix, weighted least squares, etc. However, jointly estimating all of this in a single model is preferable.

For context: I am interested in this because I am estimating an item response model where each random intercept is a person's ability at each point in time and I want to predict those abilities. I'll be doing all of this within a much more complex, Bayesian model.

```r
library(lme4)
library(tibble)
set.seed(123)

# Simulate longitudinal data
N <- 100
time <- 2

# Time-varying data
df <- tibble(person = rep(1:N, time),
           x = rnorm(N*time),       
           y = 2 + x*runif(N*time)) 

# Fit hierarchical model
mod <- lmer(y ~ -1 + (1 | person), df)

# Time-invariant data (constant within person)
df_person <- data.frame(ints = data.frame(ranef(mod))$condval,
                        sex = rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = 0.5))

# Model intercepts as function of time-invariant feature
summary(lm(ints ~ 1 + sex, df_person))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about `lme4` or `brms`, but it can be done directly in Stan.  Here's a way to replicate your model, but with everything jointly estimated; see [this example](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/radon.html#Adding-group-level-predictors) (in Python, not R) and [this paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/surveys.course/Gelman2006.pdf) for more.

## The model

We model the observed values of *y* with by-person random intercepts (one [image: alpha] for each person *j*) and a scale parameter [image: sigma].

[image: model of outcomes]

We model the by-person random intercepts as a function of the person's sex and the coefficient [image: beta], plus a second scale parameter [image: sigma alpha].

[image: model of intercepts]

## The Stan code

Here's the Stan code for the model described above.  It uses a [non-centered parameterization](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/reparameterization-section.html): "raw" values of [image: alpha] have a standard normal prior, and we convert to the "real" values of [image: alpha] using [image: beta] and [image: sigma alpha].

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N_obs; // number of observations
  int<lower=2> N_person; // number of persons
  int<lower=1,upper=N_person> person[N_obs]; // person associated with each observation
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[N_person] sex; // sex of each person
  vector[N_obs] y; // observed outcomes
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> sigma; // observation-level variation
  vector[N_person] alpha_person_raw; // random intercepts for persons
  real mu_alpha; // mean of random intercepts for persons
  real<lower=0> sigma_alpha; // scale of random intercepts for persons
  real beta; // coefficients for sex
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[N_person] alpha_person = (alpha_person_raw * sigma_alpha) +
                                  mu_alpha +
                                  (sex * beta);
}

model {
  sigma ~ exponential(1);
  alpha_person_raw ~ std_normal();
  mu_alpha ~ std_normal();
  sigma_alpha ~ exponential(1);
  beta ~ std_normal();
  y ~ normal(alpha_person[person], sigma);
}
```

## Fitting the Stan model

I recreated the dataset using the same rules as in the original example, but in a slightly different format that's easier for Stan to work with.

```
library(tidyverse)
person.df = data.frame(person = 1:N, sex = rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = 0.5))
obs.df = data.frame(person = rep(1:N, time),
                    x = rnorm(N * time)) %>%
  mutate(y = 2 + (x * runif(N * time)))

library(rstan)
stan.data = list(
  N_obs = nrow(obs.df),
  N_person = nrow(person.df),
  person = obs.df$person,
  sex = person.df$sex,
  y = obs.df$y
)
stan.model = stan("two_level_model.stan", data = stan.data, chains = 3)
```

## Comparing the two methods

First, I re-fit the two-stage model using the new datasets.

```
first.level.m = lmer(y ~ -1 + (1 | person), obs.df)
second.level.m = lm(intercept ~ 1 + sex,
                    person.df %>%
                      mutate(intercept = ranef(first.level.m)$person[["(Intercept)"]]))
```

Now, let's compare the estimated parameter values.  The two approaches agree that the effect of sex includes 0 and that the average of the random intercepts is approximately 2.  (Naturally, these estimates are influenced by the fact that `x` isn't yet included as a predictor in the models.)  They estimate approximately the same error term at the observation level, but the joint model estimates a substantially smaller error term for the model of the random intercepts.  I'm not sure how the model-fitting procedure of `lme4` relates to the exponential prior I put on [image: sigma alpha] in the Stan model.

```
library(tidybayes)
bind_rows(
  spread_draws(stan.model, mu_alpha, beta, sigma_alpha, sigma) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    dplyr::select(.draw, mu_alpha, beta, sigma_alpha, sigma) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -.draw, names_to = "parameter") %>%
    group_by(parameter) %>%
    summarise(lower.95 = quantile(value, 0.025),
              lower.50 = quantile(value, 0.25),
              est = median(value),
              upper.50 = quantile(value, 0.75),
              upper.95 = quantile(value, 0.975)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(parameter = case_when(parameter == "mu_alpha" ~ "mu[alpha]",
                                 parameter == "beta" ~ "beta",
                                 parameter == "sigma_alpha" ~ "sigma[alpha]",
                                 parameter == "sigma" ~ "sigma"),
           model = "joint"),
  summary(second.level.m)$coefficients %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("parameter") %>%
    mutate(lower.95 = Estimate + (Std..Error * qt(0.025, second.level.m$df.residual)),
           lower.50 = Estimate + (Std..Error * qt(0.25, second.level.m$df.residual)),
           est = Estimate,
           upper.50 = Estimate + (Std..Error * qt(0.75, second.level.m$df.residual)),
           upper.95 = Estimate + (Std..Error * qt(0.975, second.level.m$df.residual)),
           parameter = case_when(parameter == "(Intercept)" ~ "mu[alpha]",
                                 parameter == "sex" ~ "beta"),
           model = "two-stage") %>%
    dplyr::select(model, parameter, est, matches("lower|upper")),
  data.frame(est = summary(second.level.m)$sigma,
             parameter = "sigma[alpha]",
             model = "two-stage"),
  data.frame(est = summary(first.level.m)$sigma,
             parameter = "sigma",
             model = "two-stage")
) %>%
  mutate(parameter = fct_relevel(parameter, "beta", "mu[alpha]", "sigma[alpha]",
                                 "sigma")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = parameter, color = model)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower.95, ymax = upper.95), size = 1,
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower.50, ymax = upper.50), size = 2,
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = est), size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = scales::parse_format()) +
  labs(x = "Parameter", y = "Estimated parameter value", color = "Model") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Somewhat surprised the uncertainty bounds aren't larger given the uncertainty is propagated in the Bayesian approach.

Comment: Good point.  (Also, interestingly, the joint model estimates a smaller error term for the random intercepts; I've edited the answer to include this.)  But all the random intercepts are just noise in this dataset anyway, since there was no true person-level effect in the data-generating process.  Maybe we would see something different if there were differences by person?